# How do I sort multiple data by priority?

Tags: bash, awk, sort

I have this data in this order:
CUSTOMER-ID STATE ZIPCODE LASTNAME FIRSTNAME money_spent

```
REDACTED
```

how would I sort this data by priority?

```
1st Priority - State
2nd Priority - zipcode (descending order)
3rd Priority - lastname
4th Priority - firstname
```

I currently tried:

```
sort -t ',' -k1.1,1.1 -k12 -k13 -nr -k3.1,1.1 -k2.1,1.1 -s "summary.csv"
```

it only seems to want to sort the id

Expected output:

```
REDACTED
```

Comment: Edit the question and include which column is who and the expected output.

Comment: @Theophrastus When I copied it it removed the commas for some reason. I added back the commas

Comment: @Theophrastus Unfortunately no the states still aren't in alphabetically order

Comment: @Theophrastus let me make sure I typed that correctly - everything is running together at this point.

Comment: @Theophrastus Nevermind you are correct that worked. -k3 -nr was incorrect on my part. Good catch

Comment: Sounds like you got the answer you wanted to you should post it or close the question.

Comment: We have redacted your example data as it looked like it contained personal information. Please update your question with fake data instead.